# I am getting error while using "npm start command for React application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, cmd

I am new to react and this is my first application.
I have installed latest versions of node, npm/npx.
I created a directory using "create-react-app my-app".
After this when i enter the directory and type "npm start", I get the following error. Please help

```
C:\Users\admin\my-app>npm start

> my-app@0.1.0 start C:\Users\admin\my-app
> react-scripts start

Starting the development server...

events.js:288
     throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
     ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
←[90m    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)←[39m
←[90m    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)←[39m
←[90m    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)←[39m
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
←[90m    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)←[39m
←[90m    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)←[39m
←[90m    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)←[39m {
 errno: ←[32m'ENOENT'←[39m,
 code: ←[32m'ENOENT'←[39m,
 syscall: ←[32m'spawn cmd'←[39m,
 path: ←[32m'cmd'←[39m,
 spawnargs: [ ←[32m'/s'←[39m, ←[32m'/c'←[39m, ←[32m'start'←[39m, ←[32m'""'←[39m, ←[32m'/b'←[39m, ←[32m'"http://localhost:3000"'←[39m ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-12T15_19_48_491Z-debug.log
```

Here is my `package.json` content

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

As suggested by some, I have deleted my `node modules` folder and then did `npm update` followed by `npm install` but still i am getting the same error. Any help would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen this before. Try deleting your `node_modules` folder and after that run `npm update` and then `npm install`.

If that doesn't work there are a few answers from another forums:

- Some windows users said that add System32 to environment variables helped:

Goto `Control Panel > System` and `Security > System > Advanced system settings > Enviroment variables` and set a **system variable** to path `C:\Windows\System32\` and restart your System.

- Worst case scenario: downgrade `react-scripts` to 2.1.8 :

`npm install react-scripts@2.1.8`